# Does anyone pronounce the verb “perfect” as they would the adjective?

Tags: pronunciation, dialects

Is there anyone who pronounces the verb *perfect* as they would the adjective? For instance, would anyone say “I need to p[schwa]r-fikt my project”?

Comment: I don't think the adjective of *perfect* is one syllable though... I think you mean the stress is on the second syllable?

Comment: Yes. Sorry about that.

Comment: Adj., noun /ˈpəːfɪkt/ ; verb /pəˈfɛkt/ https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/perfect

Comment: That doesn’t really answer my question.

Comment: The rest of the question, if any is I am afraid, OT on ELU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I lived and worked for over 20 years in Australia and England. No one ever pronounced "**to perfect**" as they would say "perfect-adj.". I think it is easy and natural for the speaker to put the stress on the second syllable, because of an automatic memory for such words like "**perfection and perfectionist**".